# How to implement a quit option into my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, simulator, dice

hi I'm fairly new to programming and am currently writing the classic dice rolling simulator in python 3.6.

I'm trying to make it as user-friendly as I can hence the amount of code there is, I've written the code and it works but I'm having trouble creating a part of the code where if the user types in 'quit' into the 'usersInput' variable it will break the loop and quit the program.

I'm not currently sure on where and how to place this condition into the code any help will be of great thanks.

```
import math
import random
import time

numberList = [4,6,8,10,12,20] #list of dice sides


print ('\n'*100) #keeping the screen clean!

print("Hello User!") #Intro welcome

nameLoop = 0 #loop variable

while nameLoop <= 0:#start a loop for inputting name
    usersName = str(input("Please enter your name:"))
    if len(usersName) <= 0 or usersName == ' ':
        print('\n'*100 + "You need to enter a name")
    else:
        nameLoop += 1
        print ('\n'*100)
        print ("Hi "+usersName+","+" let's get started")
        time.sleep(3)

print ('\n'*50)
returnProgram = 0#loop variable
while returnProgram ==0:#returns user to the welcome page
    print ("Welcome to the dice rolling simulator!")#welcome page
    print ('\n')#new line


    try:
        usersInput = int(input("""To roll a die please input how many sides
you would like the die to have or press the
*ENTER* key to choose from a list:"""))
        if usersInput == 0:#catches if a user tries to randomize a number between 0 and 0
            print ('\n'*100)
            print("That's not enough sides! Try again!")#error message
            time.sleep(2)
            print ('\n'*100)
            continue#continues loop and returns to welcome message
    except ValueError:#perform action if input isnt an integer
        print ('\n'*100)
        print("Type '0' to return")
        print ("Choose a number from the list:")
        print (numberList)#callinf a list of pres-selected numbers to roll from

        numListInputLoop = 0#loop variable
        while numListInputLoop == 0:#enters loop for user to input more than one option from 'numberList'
            try:
                numListInput = int(input(":"))
            except ValueError:
                print("That's not a valid input")#catches if a user tries to enter a word/letter
                print(numberList)#reprints list of number options
                continue#continues loop until user inputs an integer
            else:#runs this code when a user inupts a valid integer
                if numListInput == 4:#runs dice roll code for each option on the number list
                    print("The dice rolled a %d" % random.randint(1,4))
                elif numListInput == 6:
                    print("The dice rolled a %d" % random.randint(1,6))
                elif numListInput == 8:
                    print("The dice rolled a %d" % random.randint(1,8))
                elif numListInput == 10:
                    print("The dice rolled a %d" % random.randint(1,10))
                elif numListInput == 12:
                    print("The dice rolled a %d" % random.randint(1,12))
                elif numListInput == 20:
                    print("The dice rolled a %d" % random.randint(1,20))
                elif numListInput == 0:
                    numListInputLoop += 1#exits 'numListInputLoop' loop to return to welcome page
                    print ('\n'*100)
                else:
                    print("That's not in the list of options")#incase the user tries to enter anything else
                    print(numberList)

    else:#perform action if 'usersInput' is a integer
        if usersInput == 1:#just for printing plural or singular version of the word 'side(s)'
            print ('\n'*100)
            print("You wish to roll a die with %d side" % usersInput)#singular
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            print ('\n'*100)
            print("You wish to roll a die with %d sides" % usersInput)#plural
            time.sleep(2)

        diceRoll = ("%s rolled a %s sided die" % (usersName,usersInput))
        rollingOne = ("Rolling.")
        rollingTwo = ("Rolling..")
        rollingThree = ("Rolling...")

        print('\n'*100)
        print(rollingOne)
        time.sleep(1)
        print('\n'*100)
        print(rollingTwo)
        time.sleep(1)
        print('\n'*100)
        print(rollingThree)
        time.sleep(1)
        print('\n'*100)
        print(rollingOne)
        time.sleep(1)
        print('\n'*100)
        print(rollingTwo)
        time.sleep(1)
        print('\n'*100)
        print(rollingThree)
        time.sleep(1)
        print ('\n'*100)#gimicy loading screen ;)

        print(diceRoll)
        print("The die landed on %s" % random.randint(1,usersInput))
        time.sleep(5)
        print ('\n'*100)
```

Comment: Where all the methods? Why do you need 3 rollings?

Comment: Just use the classic `while True:` loop, take an input string via `input` and if it equals to `'q'` or whatever string you want to enter to quit then `break`, otherwise continue with the rest of your code. There is a dupe on So somewhere, I cant find it, but the code is something like [this](https://ideone.com/1sDzJK).

Comment: @PaulRooney hi thanks for the response Paul where in this code would you suggest I place the while true statement or should I alter an existing while statement and replace it with your suggestion

Comment: I think `while returnProgram ==0:` (line 32) is the one you want to replace. You also need to not immediately convert your input string to int, but wait until after you know its not a quit command.

Comment: Also try breaking your code down into a couple of functions. It will make your control flow clearer and eliminate large sections of code inside `try/except` blocks.

Comment: @PaulRooney thanks paul I added
    elif usersInput == "quit":
                break
            usersInput = int(usersInput)
and removed the first instance of int() to the usersInput variable
after 'quit' had been defined
ill work on using functions and methods in my next project still don't understand them, thanks for the help

Comment: ok cool, but did it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following option using [exit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit)

```
elif numListInput == -1:
    exit(0)
```